# Custom back button removing view from navigationBar

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, xamarin.ios

I have a custom button on my view and I want it to do the same functionality as the system-default back button on a navigation Bar = simply remove a view from navigationController displayed by NavigationController.PushViewController(cc, false);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try NavigationController.PopViewController()

Comment: Thnx for help. I did not find a useful documentation for this and also did not find 'Pop' in my dictionary. How easy!